# Git get latest changes before pushing a branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control, branching-and-merging, git-checkout

I have a local branch `features` that I based off of my local `master` to add some stuff in my code. I am now ready to merge those back into `master` , however, the state of the remote `master` branch has changed since then.

How can I get the latest version of master and then add my changes on top of that, so that I can then make a pull request to my remote `master` branch.

I read a couple of similar articles here, but all of them gave different answers and I got confused.

Should I first "switch" to my master branch, do a `git pull` and then somehow merge my `features` branch into it (resolving any conflicts), or is there another way.

Some articles pointed out the usage of `git checkout branch features`, but I am not sure what is the point in that. As far as I understand it `git checkout` just switches to a certain branch.

Can anyone point me in a correct direction as to how I might approach this. Again, I just need to get the latest changes of my remote `master` branch so that when I push my `features` branch I dont get a ton of conflicts.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Go to `master` branch with: `git checkout master`
2. Update your local `master` with: `git pull origin master`
3. Resolve conflicts (if applicable)
4. Go back to `features` with: `git checkout features`
5. Merge `master` branch over `features` with: `git merge master`
6. Push changes with: `git push origin features`

Now, you have to create a new pull request from `features` to `master`. Done!

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. One more question though - You say that I merge `features` with `master`. Would it be wrong if i do this the other way around - merge `master` into `features`. I am thinking of doing this, since when I create the pull request I want it to show that its from my features branch, not my `master` branch. This is not really an issue, I am just curious. Again, thanks for the wonderful answer

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact, that's how I do it! I have edited the answer. Glad to help you.

Comment: @Héctor Thanks for such a nice and clean explanation.  And thank you Kobek for asking, I have had same problems as you understanding this.

Comment: @Héctor I have a question though.  I created features branch, added some changes, stage, committed and then did git push -u origin feature.  Then I wanted to make sure my master is updated with remote master, so I switched to my master and did what you explained above.  git pull origin master reported "All up to date".  I checked out feature and did git status without merge and now I see all files (that I added/modified previously and pushed using -u to remote) as either "to be committed", or as "staged", or as "untracked".  Why is this?  Was something wrong in what I did?